# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children(...)[0].css is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am getting this error in my jQuery selector when I am trying to get my table's all rows' height value in a for loop.

This is the selector I use to traverse all rows of the table:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = $('#table-' + currentGraphOptions.id +' > tbody').children()[i];

    var rowsHeight = currentRow.css('height');
}
```

The error on the title is as a result of rowsHeight.

This is full error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children(...)[0].css is not a function
at Scope.eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:1:65)
at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:55)
at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:964:21)
at Scope.controllers.controller.$scope.saveDashboard (http://localhost:9001/scripts/controllers/DashboardCtrl.js:497:61)
at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12404:18)
at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:21566:17)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14466:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14565:23)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:21571:23)
```

Comment: Try wrapping currentRow in $: `var rowsHeight = $(currentRow).css('height');`

Comment: When accessing element from the array jQuery uses to store then you take the pure DOM element so you lose all jQuery methods attach to a jQuery insteance object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are working with DOM node instead of jQuery object. Use `.children().eq(i)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the DOM element from your jQuery object and DOM elements don't have a `.css()` method.

You may mean to use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
for (var i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = $('#table-' + currentGraphOptions.id +' > tbody').children().eq(i);
    var rowsHeight = currentRow.css('height');
}
```